# Control.ValueChanged fire with time offset

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have some C# controls like `NumericUpDown` or `TextBox` and want to fire an event with an offset of some seconds. In the past, I have accomplished this behaviour with a `Timer`. The code which I am working on uses a `BackgroundWorker` to accomplish this. On some other places, I found normal Threads to build this behaviour.

The reason why one might want an offset is, for example, a time-consuming method which is executed after each ValueChange of a NumericUpDown. If a user clicks several times on the down arrow only the last Click should be of importance because this is the value which the user wanted in the end.

The way I used to handle this looks as follows

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /*
     * Designer Code
    this.eventOffsetTimer.Interval = 500;
    this.eventOffsetTimer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.eventOffsetTimer_Tick);
    */
    eventOffsetTimer.Stop();
    eventOffsetTimer.Start();
}

private void eventOffsetTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    eventOffsetTimer.Stop();
    //Time consuming stuff...
    MessageBox.Show(numericUpDown1.Value.ToString());
}
```

I was wondering what the best practice is to accomplish an offset of some seconds before the event is fired. Is there a built-in way which Microsoft encourages to use? Starting and stopping a Timer is a simple thing to do but it seems there could be a Microsoft encouraged method.

Comment: You should use `.Restart()` after using `.Stop()` to reset the timer.

Comment: I wasn't aware of a System.Windows.Forms.Timer.Restart(). There seems to be no Restart method in the Microsoft documentation. Which Timer do you mean?

Comment: My fault: I usually use `System.Timer` which has a `.Restart()`, because `.Start()` only continues the current run. I don't know any build-in solution. I think you have to build your own. This might be interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648700/is-there-a-way-to-delay-an-event-handler-say-for-1-sec-in-windows-forms

Comment: Best practices these days would be to go async/await and cancel-then-recreate a delay-fronted task.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.Restart()`. It first releases Timer then Starts it again.

Tips: You do not need to use `.Stop()` with `.Restart()`

Comment: I wasn't aware of a System.Windows.Forms.Timer.Restart(). There seems to be no Restart method in the Microsoft documentation. Which Timer do you mean?

Comment: you can use `System.Timers.Timer`